# Setting max_execution_time per cron job

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am running a particular WordPress cron job which takes a lot of time to complete as it does remote requests.

I want to increase the `max_execution_time` of only this task.

If I use `ini_set()` inside the cron function like the following will it work?

```
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'cronjob' );

add_action( 'cronjob', 'cronjob_func' );

function cronjob_func() {
    @ini_set( "max_execution_time", 600 );
    //Rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time, yes, unless safe mode is enabled.